# Error in running SVM and Logistic Regression in python

Tags: python, svm, logistic-regression

I am trying to tune the parameter between the SVM, Logistic regression, MLP and Random forest regression in the python but it shows a value error for SVM and logistic regression. 
my sample data is this:

```
Wavelength    Phase_velocity     Shear_wave_velocity
1.50              202.69          240.73
1.68              192.72          240.73
1.79              205.54          240.73
17.08             218               229
16.73             243               269
17.72             245               269
16.72             212               253
17.26             214               253
........
```

The example code is:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


df = pd.read_csv("0.5-1.csv")
df.head()

X = df[['wavelength', 'phase velocity']]
y = df['shear wave velocity']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

print (len(X_train),len(X_test),len(y_train),len(y_test))

lr = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear',multi_class='ovr')
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
print (lr.score(X_test, y_test))

svm = SVC(gamma='auto')
svm.fit(X_train, y_train)
print (svm.score(X_test, y_test))

mlp = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(50,50,50), max_iter=2000, activation='relu')
mlp.fit(X_train,y_train)
print (mlp.score(X_test, y_test))

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=40)
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print (rf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

the error is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\My Drive\ANN\test\0.5-1\0.5-1_tunecode.py", line 23, in <module>
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "C:\Users\sadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\logistic.py", line 1533, in fit
    check_classification_targets(y)
  File "C:\Users\sadia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 169, in check_classification_targets
    raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)
ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Your target variable `shear wave velocity` looks like a continuous variable so you should not be using `logisticRegression` or `SVC` try something like a linear regression or `SVR`.

Comment: i updated the table in the question box. the shear wave velocity is continuous but it is for specific data. for this data, cant I use the svc or logistic regression?

Comment: How many unique values in your label?

Comment: there's no specific unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your target variable is continuous in nature, you cannot use `logisticRegression`, use a `linearRegression` or `SVR` instead of `SVC`.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVR
```

Comment: thank you but what is the difference between them. I am quite new in this field.

Comment: I would encourage you to go through this https://machinelearningmastery.com/classification-versus-regression-in-machine-learning/